# 'OpenFileDialog' is a type and cannot be used as an expression

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

Hi I'm getting an error as the OpenFileDialog and SaveFileDialog  is a type and cannot be used as an expression could you please help me out in fixing those errors[image: error]

```
     Private Sub btnEncode_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        Using (SaveFileDialog sfd = New SaveFileDialog() {Filter() = "JPEG|*.jpg", ValidateNames = True})

            If (sfd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then

                MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec().QRCodeEncodere(encoder) = New 
                MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec.QRCodeEncoder()
                encoder.QRCodeScale = 8
                Bitmap(bmp) = encoder.Encode(txt.Encode.Text)
                PictureBox.Image = bmp
                bmp.Save(sfd.FileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDecode_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        Using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "JPEG|*.jpg", ValidateNames = true, Multiselct - False})

            If (ofd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then

                PictureBox.Image = Image.FromeFile(ofd.FileName)
                MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec.QRCodeDecoder(Decoder) = New 
                MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec.QRCodeDecoder()
                txtDecode.Text = decoder.Decode(New QRCodeBitmapImage = (PictureBox.ImageBitmap))
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Comment: This looks more like VB than C# :) In any case, could you provide the full exception and stack trace of the exception you are getting? It's not clear to me where in this piece of code you would get an error - if the issue even is in this piece.

Comment: I'm into a learning phase could you please help me as how to get the stack trace

Comment: The stack trace/call stack is a property on the exception you're getting. You can [see in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/exception-helper?view=vs-2019) what it looks like

Comment: If it's VB, it should be `Using sfd As SaveFileDialog = New SaveFileDialog()`

Comment: I have tried this things if anyone can contact me on manojgaidhankar@gmail.com on hangouts it would be a great help so that I can screenshare and show you

Answer (score -1):

You seem to have mixed up C# and VB.NET completely. If you were to write fully in  VB.NET, the code would be:

```
 Private Sub btnEncode_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        Using sfd As SaveFileDialog = New SaveFileDialog() With {.Filter = "JPEG|*.jpg", .ValidateNames = True})

            If sfd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then

                Dim encoder As MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec().QRCodeEncoder = New MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec.QRCodeEncoder()
                encoder.QRCodeScale = 8
                Dim bmp As Bitmap = encoder.Encode(txtEncode.Text)
                PictureBox.Image = bmp
                bmp.Save(sfd.FileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDecode_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        Using ofd As OpenFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog() With {.Filter = "JPEG|*.jpg", .ValidateNames = True, .Multiselect = False})

            If ofd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                PictureBox.Image = Image.FromeFile(ofd.FileName)
                Dim decoder As MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec.QRCodeDecoder = New MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec.QRCodeDecoder()
                txtDecode.Text = decoder.Decode(New QRCodeBitmapImage(PictureBox.ImageBitmap))
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub
```

and if you wanted to write it fully in C#, the code would be:

```
 private void btnEncode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        using (SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog() {Filter = "JPEG|*.jpg", ValidateNames = True})
        {
            if(sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec().QRCodeEncoder encoder = new MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec.QRCodeEncoder();
                encoder.QRCodeScale = 8;
                Bitmap bmp = encoder.Encode(txtEncode.Text);
                PictureBox.Image = bmp;
                bmp.Save(sfd.FileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            }
        }
}

private void btnDecode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "JPEG|*.jpg", ValidateNames = true, Multiselect = False})
        {
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                PictureBox.Image = Image.FromeFile(ofd.FileName);
                MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec.QRCodeDecoder decoder = New 
                MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec.QRCodeDecoder();
                txtDecode.Text = decoder.Decode(New QRCodeBitmapImage(PictureBox.ImageBitmap));
            }
       }
}
```

The PictureBox control doesn't have an attribute named "ImageBitmap", so I'm not sure if you meant "Image"